# logic: unification of a formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

apply the unification algorithm to the following two clauses and show how it progresss towards finding a most general unifier or concluding that the clause is not unifiable?

{P(x,y),P(y,f(z))},{P(g(x),y),P(y,y),P(u,f(w))}

can somebody show me how to do it step by step and explain the meaning of it.
im a bit lost on this section(about the unifier and general unifier)

by the way im using the book "logic for computer scientists"　by uwe schoning

based on the algorithm in p.84 of the textbook.

this is what i have done: for the clause {P(x,y),P(y,f(z))} i have the substitution as sub=sub[x/y][y/f(z)]  and the most general unifier as Lsub={P(f(z),f(z))}

for the second clause  {P(g(x),y),P(y,y),P(u,f(w))}
i follow the unifier algorithm 
step1:sub=sub[y/g(x)] and has a result as {P(g(x),g(x)}
step2:sub=sub[u/g(x)] and has a result as {P(g(x),f(w)}
step3:since non of "f" and "g" is variable. so output non-unifiable

Comment: What is the unification algorithm of your text?  I see this, but I'm not familiar with details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29

Comment: You have to "link together" all the steps : 1) Skolem normal form, 2) Herbrand expansion, 3) resolution, 4) unification. All with the aim to find a "refutation" of $\lnot \varphi$ (i.e.to show that it is unsatisfiable trough a proof taht the corrisponding clause set is unsatisfiable). But if $\lnot \varphi$ is *unsatisfiable*, then $\varphi$ is *valid*.

Comment: I've expanded my answer; a very good book on this topic is : Melvin Fitting, [First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving](http://www.amazon.com/First-Order-Automated-Theorem-Proving-Computer/dp/1461275156/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1398965143&sr=1-1&keywords=Melvin+Fitting+First-Order+Logic+and+Automated+Theorem+Proving) (1st ed : 1990).

Comment: I'm not sure about the last step for the second clause; if you use sub[u/f(g(x))] and sub[w/g(x)], you will have as result : {P(f(g(x)),f(g(x))}... Does it works ?

Comment: i dont think it can be applied with sub[u/f(g(x))] the first predicate symbol has a term, g(x). there is no way to subst g(x) into f(g(x)). am i right? as to the first clause. what you think about my answer?

Comment: For the first one, it looks good to me.

Comment: @PawanHsu - as you said, we obtain from step 1 : {P(g(x),g(x)}. But I'm still thinking that in step 2 you can do : sub[u/f(g(x))][w/g(x)].

Answer (score 4):

See page 83 :

> Now we introduce the predicate logic version of *resolution*. The new idea is to resolve clauses in predicate logic to clauses in predicate logic where each resolution step is
>   accompanied by a substitution. These substitutions are performed in a guarded manner.
>
> For example, in the case of the two clauses $\{ P(x), \lnot Q(g(x)) \}$ and $\{ \lnot P(f(y)) \}$, it suffices to use the substitution $[x/f(y)]$ to obtain the resolvent $\{ \lnot Q(g(f(y)) \}$. There is no need at this point to substitute anything for the variable $y$.

The "trick is that with the above subst, we will have :

> $\{ P(f(y)), \lnot Q(g(f(y))) \}$ and $\{ \lnot P(f(y)) \}$

so that we have unified the two *literals* $P(x)$ and $P(f(y))$.

> Central for the following investigations is the search for a substitution which *unifies* two or more literals, i.e., makes them identical. In the above example, $[x/f(y)]$ unifies the two literals $P(x)$ and $P(f(y))$. The substitution $[x/f(a)] [y/a]$ would also be a unifier but does not satisfy the definition of a most general unifier.
>
> In a sense (defined formally below), this substitution makes more substitutions than necessary.

The **Unification Algorithm** is described at page 84.

You have to recall the *resolution* calculus [page 29] :

> Resolution is a simple syntactic transformation applied to formulas. From two given formulas in a resolution step (provided resolution is applicable to the formulas), a third formula is generated. This new formula can then be used in further resolution steps, and so on. [...] the task is to prove *unsatisfiability* of a given formula.

In *propositional* logic, first you transform a formula $F$ in **CNF** ;

$F = (L_{1,1} \lor ... \lor L_{1,n_1}) \land ... \land (L_{k,1} \lor ... \lor L_{k,n_k})$ ;

the we represent the **CNF** as sets of *clauses* where a clause is a set of literals:

$F = \{ \{ L_{1,1},... L_{1,n_1} \}, ... \{ L_{k,1}, ... L_{k,n_k} \} \}$.

The resolution procedure "simplify" the set of clauses until reach an end; if the result of the last step is the *empty clause*, then the "initial" clause set is *unsatisfiable*. By property of the **CNF**, also the initial formula is *unsatisfiable*.

Thus, if the initial formula was $\varphi$, having shown that it is *unsatisfiable*, we conclude that $\lnot \varphi$ is a *tautology*.

In *predicate* logic, the basic concepts are the same; we say that a formula is *valid* instead of *tautological*, but the aim of the procedure is the same : to check if the initial formula is *unsatisfiable*.

In this case, we start with an initial formula and transform it into **RPF**; then produce its *Skolem formula*; recall that [Theorem page 57] :

> For each formula $\varphi$ in **RPF**, $\varphi$ is satisfiable if and only if its *Skolem form* is *satisfiable*.

Finally, convert the *matrix* of the *Skolem formula* into **CNF** [see page 60].

From now on, we apply the resolution procedure; in predicate logic it is more complicated, due to the "richer" semantics for f-o language.

We need the *Herbrand universe* and the *Herbrand expansion*, and *unification*, but the goal is the same : transform the clause set in order to find if it is *unsatisfiable*.

If so, "rewinding" the above process, we have that the *Skolem formula* is *unsat*, and thus the **RPF** is; finally, also the initial formula $\varphi$ is *unsat*, and thus we conclude that $\lnot \varphi$ is *valid*.

Comment: i have add my work in the content. can u help to see if this is correct or wrong? thanks you very much.